# What am I supposed to say?

Tags: cipher

While at the bar the other day, a friend of mine slapped $500 cash on the table along with a piece of paper, on which was written

**MVR YCBMD AAVO JASVQ'M WBTBZ LLVXD'F YCGD.**

He said if I could manage to decrypt this text, and then say it three times, the money is mine. And I could sure use the cash.

Can you help me? What am I supposed to say?

Comment: Is there any info for decrypting the cipher provided up there?

Comment: yes there is a clue

Comment: Just as a question, is the story fluff, or real? :P

Comment: I wish it were real! :)

Comment: I'm guessing this is a tongue twister when decrypted.

Comment: TGE- Yes it is :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer

> **THE SIXTH SICK SHEIK'S SIXTH SHEEP'S SICK.**

Key

> Tongue twister

Go ahead and say it!! :)

Comment: nice work! :) Once I saw that comment from TheGreatEscaper, I knew it was just a matter of time! :D

Comment: And once you confirmed there was a clue, I think I got it. :) Nice!

Comment: I know there's a lot of long winded complex puzzles in here that sometimes last for weeks. However, there's a place for short ones as well. :) And you basically went Alan Turing on this one!!!! :D

Comment: Oh, its a weekend. Else it could have been someone else ;)